# Voice enabled-keyboard in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, voice

I want see the source code for the voice enabled-keyboard feature for android.
Can someone tell me where to find the code?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're referring to the speech recognition feature demonstrated on the Nexus One with Android 2.1.

If this application is open sourced as part of Android, it will be posted on the Android Open Source Project website at https://android.googlesource.com.

However, Android 2.1 has not yet been posted; it should hopefully be available soon.

In the meantime, you could take a look at the source to the [voice dialler application](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/VoiceDialer).

Comment: thnx .. the source for the voice dialer is useful!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this code is not currently planned to be open sourced -- it is owned by Google as part of their voice recognition server technology.  The IME is a fork that Google made of the standard platform input method, adding voice search to it, much like other manufacturers make their own proprietary customizations.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. Though I guess this is slightly different from other vendor customisations if the input method requires an internet connection!

Comment: :( too bad it was my chance for getting the speech recognition code.